# why is moving the definition of the operator() from .h to .cpp file causing a data race?

Tags: c++, header, locking, mutex

in my code I have the following header files:

Global.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_
#include <mutex>
namespace
{
    std::mutex outputMutex;
}
#endif
```

Test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_
#include"Global.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
class TestClass
{
    std::string name;
public:
    TestClass(std::string n):name{n}{}
    void operator()()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<30;++i)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(outputMutex);
            std::cout<<name<<name<<name<<name<<name<<name<<name<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

Test2.h is actually equal to Test1.h, only containing a class called *"TestClass2"* instead of *"TestClass"*.
My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Global.h"
#include "Test.h"
#include "Test2.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TestClass obj1("Hello");
    TestClass2 obj2("GoodBye");
    thread t1(obj1);
    thread t2(obj2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

If I run the program like this I get the expected output:

> HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello

or

> GoodByeGoodByeGoodByeGoodByeGoodByeGoodByeGoodBye

So far so good. But when I put the definition of the ()-operator of Test.h and Test2.h in source files Test.cpp and Test2.cpp:

(Test.cpp, same for Test2.cpp):

```
#include "Test.h"
#include"Global.h"

void TestClass::operator()()
{
    for (int i=0;i<30;++i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(outputMutex);
        std::cout<<name<<name<<name<<name<<name<<name<<name<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

and accordingly remove the definition from the header-files: `void operator()();` I suddenly start getting occasional outputs like this:

> GoodByeHelloGoodByeHelloGoodByeHelloGoodByeHelloGoodByeHelloGoodByeHelloGoodByeHello

I don't know why the lock with the mutex variable `outputMutex` doesn't work any more, but I assume it has something to do with two versions of the variable being created, but I'd love to get a professional explanation. I'm using Eclipse with Cygwin.

Comment: That mutex is different for every translation unit. Just make it a mutable member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mixture of undefined behavior and anonymous namespaces.

First this:

```
namespace {
  std::mutex outputMutex;
}
```

this is an anonymous namespace containing the mutex `outputMatrix`.  A different `outputMatrix` exists in *every source file*, as it has a different name.

That is what anonymous namespaces do.  Think of them as "generate unique guid here for each cpp file that builds this".  They are intended to prevent link-time symbol collisions.

```
class TestClass {
  std::string name;
public:
  // ...
  void operator()() {
    // ...
  }
};
```

this is an (implicitly) `inline` `TestClass::operator()`.  Its body is compiled in each compilation unit.  By the ODR the body *must be the same in every compilation unit*, or your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  (methods defined inside a class definition are implicitly `inline`, with all that baggage).

It uses a token from an anonymous namespace.  This token has a different meaning in each compilation unit.  If there is more than one compilation unit, the result is an ill-formed program with no diagnostic required; the C++ standard places no restrictions on its behavior<sup>1</sup>.

In this particular case, the same compilation unit was chosen for `operator()` from `TestClass` and `TestClass2`.  So it used the same mutex.  This is not reliable; a partial rebuild could cause it to change, or the phases of the moon.

When you put it into its own `.cpp` file, it was no longer implicitly `inline`.  Only one definition existed, but they where in separate compilation units.

These two different compilation units got a different `outputMatrix` mutex.

---

<sup>1</sup> The most common effect of violating that particular rule is that the linker picks one implementation based on arbitrary criteria (that can change from build to build!), and silently discards the rest.  This is not good, as innocuous changes to the build process (adding more cores, partial builds, etc) can break your code.  Don't violate the "inline functions must have the same definition everywhere" rule.  This is just the most common symptom; you are not guaranteed to have anything this sensible happen.

Comment: thx for your elaborate answer. So do you say that the "only header files version" worked just by coincidence? I'm just surprised because I got it from a notable reference book. Is it a better solution just to create a struct/class "mutexStruct" in Global.h with a public mutex member variable and create a reference to a  "mutexStruct" object in TestClass and TestClass2?

Comment: @airborne If would reliably work if there was only one .cpp file.  Anonymous namespaces in header files are extremely dangerous when mixed with `inline` code (either explicitly inline, or functions defined in bodies of classes).  `extern` lets you have one object publicly exposed but only "exists" within one particular cpp file; note that undefined static initialization order means it isn't generally safe to use it before the start of `main`.